# Bayesian Network Probability For Child Node

Tags: artificial-intelligence, probability, bayesian, bayesian-networks

Given the following Bayesian network determine the probabilities.

[image]

On the network shown in Figure 1, suppose that:

```
P("alternator broken"=true) = 0.02
P("no charging"=true | "alternator broken"=true) = 0.95
P("no charging"=true | "alternator broken"=false) = 0.01.
What is P("no charging"=false)? How is it derived?
```

How would you go about determining "no charging" without having information about "fanbelt broken"?
Would the following be true: 
**P("no charging"=false)** = 
**P("alternator broken"=true)** * **P("no charging"=true | "alternator broken"=true)** +  **P("alternator broken"= false)** * **P("no charging"=true | "alternator broken"= false)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's not possible

To calculate `P("no charging")` for the given BN, you are missing the prior for `fanbelt broken`. *And also the CPT for `no charging` is underspecified*, because `no charging` depends on `fanbelt broken`.

### But you might want to

The best you can do with the information you have is simply ignore `fanbelt broken`. If the values for `P( "charging" | "alternator broken")` are obtained by taking the correct expectation over `fanbelt broken`, then the result is correct. If the latter is true this means that `fanbelt broken` is already eliminated (summed out), and it's influence is incorporated into the CPT for ´charging`.